# What does the bytes (like `0x34`) mean in the module specs?

Tags: cosmos-sdk

In the specs of the Cosmos SDK, what does the byte `0x34` in a line like this mean?

Redelegations: `0x34 | DelegatorAddr | ValidatorSrcAddr | ValidatorDstAddr -> amino(redelegation)`

And I guess `amino` is the decoder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build a blockchain with Cosmos SDK, there is a [key-value store abstraction](https://docs.cosmos.network/master/core/store.html) for interacting with the on-chain data. Each module has its own KV store. A module may want to store different types of data in its store and so prefixes are used to differentiate between different types in the store.

In your example, in the `staking` module there are "redelegations" and each redelegation is stored in the store with a prefix of `0x34`. There are [keys for other types](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/90e9370bd80d9a3d41f7203ddb71166865561569/x/staking/types/keys.go#L40) as well.

Answer (score 1):

`0x34` is the hexadecimal number `34`. It corresponds with the decimal number `3*16+4=52`. The `|` is a binary operator that uses infix notation and calculates the `logical or` of the two operands.

Comment: I could have been clearer. I meant, what is the purpose of the byte? I got the answer from Denis, though. And thanks for clearing up the fact that `|` is concatenation, I was reading this as an EBF grammar. Is there a place where this notation is recorded?